# Weird shell prompt (PS) in shell scripts running under another shell type

Tags: zsh, prompt

When I run a `#!/bin/sh` script containing `set -o xtrace` in an interactive `zsh` I get weird output looking like `%F{red}>> %f`. Obviously the PS4 of my `.zshrc` is used but the interpreting shell is sh. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `export` the PS4 variable whenever you're setting it in your ~/.zshrc. Just set it as if it were an internal variable (which is what it is).